# Symfony2, load user from database login returning 'Bad Credentials'

Tags: security, symfony, authentication

Currently at my wits end on this process. I've been following [Symfony's tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html) on loading users from the database and have not gotten it to work properly.

My security.yml:
http://pastebin.com/cczdxxqG

User.php:
http://pastebin.com/Yh53bXp6

UserRepository.php:
http://pastebin.com/6pL6uYQW

Role.php:
http://pastebin.com/G5RnxHDi

SecurityController.php:
http://pastebin.com/ynZgPfSj

Twig template for login form:

```
<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post" class="login">

    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" /><br />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" /><br />

    {#
        If you want to control the URL the user
        is redirected to on success (more details below)
        <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
    #}

    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token"
        value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">

    <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

When I login with username: admin and password: adminpass it works fine but it won't load the users from the database. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Does it mean you cannot log in with users defined in DB? Are you sure you have users in DB and roles are assigned them correctly?

Comment: @Javad yes I can't log in with users defined in DB but was able to log in as in memory users.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your security.yml that it does not recognize your Custom UserProvider, change it as below

```
providers:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [in_memory, user_db]
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
    user_db:
        entity: { class: Bundle:User }
```

Because you have a custom user provider you don't need to pass the `property: username`
On the other hand I am not sure about your bundle name if it is `CIRBundle` or `Bundle`

Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

check the column password in your database table.Maybe it too short.Modify it to VARCHAR(100) or 200